# Is it possible to take HTML code that is displayed as text on a webpage and read it as HTML on another site?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, text

I have data that is constantly updated that I need to use in my HTML. While I can create the HTML code using Google Sheets and make it public, the problem is that this creates text instead of readable HTML.

I need to find a way to embed the text from this URL as HTML code on another website, so that whenever the information is updated, the HTML code is as well:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1tGqU_y62F0-YgQ953RWV2vhMFFprCTs5e7E0KtSNCHg/pubhtml?gid=1350637925&single=true&range=A1&chrome=false&gridlines=false

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM API methods like innerHTML to insert your HTML:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML .

so something like: 
`document.getElementById("yourcontainer").innerHTML =`

and set that to the return of your AJAX call that fetches your code

Comment: I should probably mention that I'm absolute terrible at javascript. Would I just put that as a script? Where would I put the URL?

Comment: i haven't used google sheets in the way you're using it here, so you'd have to see if it provides some publicly accessible endpoint (URL) - when I click your link, it asks me to login. once you do that, you can pick a way to perform a network request, for example Fetch API, jQuery ajax, XMLHttpRequest, etc. That will make a request to your google sheet endpoint, return your HTML code, and then you can execute your callback, which would be something like the code above, which then takes that code and outputs it to the page

Comment: Strange, here is the embeded link:

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGqU_y62F0-YgQ953RWV2vhMFFprCTs5e7E0KtSNCHg/pubhtml?gid=1350637925&amp;single=true&range=A1&chrome=false&gridlines=false"></iframe>

The URL above works for me on all browsers and when i'm not signed in, strange that it's requesting you to log in.

Which network request do you suggest?

Comment: hm, that link gives me a 'Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.'

Comment: i usually use Fetch API to make requests, although if you need to support certain older browsers, you can check out how to do a XMLHttpRequest, it's just more verbose but in this case, both would be equivalent